# Conditional destructuring array of objects es6

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, ecmascript-2016

stackblitz: [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c96bhj?file=app/app.component.ts)

The idea is the server sends a response in the below format, based on the following conditions needs to decide to show or hide the button on a page and each button has individual click functions. that's what I have static declare the button in a page.

I have below an array of objects. I need to map the object's properties to other properties with some conditions.

```
collections = [
  {
    "productId": "samsung",
    "productParams": "",
    "isAvailable": true
  },
  {
    "productId": "nokia",
    "productParams": "",
    "isAvailable": true
  },
  {
    "productId": "Lg",
    "productParams": "",
    "isAvailable": false
  },
]
```

Here is a collection array of objects.
Here I try to map the object's properties based on two conditions,

if `productId` value matches `'string'` and `isAvailable` property is `true` I have assigned to a global variable and show the button. But it works wrong. Anyone help the code what I did wrong.

```
getClick() {
  let showButtonSamsung, showButtonNokia, showButtonLg;
  let x = this.collections.map(x => {
    showButtonSamsung = x.productId == 'samsung' && x.isAvailable == true ? true : false;
    showButtonNokia = x.productId =='nokia' && x.isAvailable == true ? true : false;
    showButtonLg = x.productId == 'Lg' && x.isAvailable == true ? true : false;
  });
}
```

expected O/P:

```
showButtonSamsung: true  // will show the button
showButtonNokia: true  // will show the button
showButtonLg: false  // hide the button
```

Comment: "Mapping" means producing a new array. You're basically just looping, and storing the results from your last iteration in the global variables. What do you actually want as the result?

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with destructuring, es6, or es7.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing here ? and what you are getting according to ur logic ?

Comment: Why are you not iterating through collection and setting the status of button based on `isAvailable` property? You can map this and assign to your three variable.

Comment: @bergi , you are correct ,I am not doing destructing here ,just map and assign last iteration to global variables.still stuck in the code and es6 destructing object concepts

Comment: @ Hassan Imam the server sends a response in the above format, I have 20 buttons in a page, based on the property names and the available property is true, I need to show the buttons and each button has an individual click function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `reduce` would be much better in this case.

```js
let collections = [{
    "productId": "samsung",
    "productParams": "",
    "isAvailable": true
  },
  {
    "productId": "nokia",
    "productParams": "",
    "isAvailable": true
  },

  {
    "productId": "Lg",
    "productParams": "",
    "isAvailable": false
  }
]


const map = {
  samsung: "showButtonSamsung",
  nokia: "showButtonNokia",
  Lg: "showButtonLg"
}

const {showButtonSamsung, showButtonNokia, showButtonLg} = collections.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const property = map[obj.productId];
  acc[property] = obj.isAvailable;
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(showButtonSamsung, showButtonNokia, showButtonLg);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more or less what you're looking for:

```
 const collections = [
    {
        "productId": "samsung",
        "productParams": "",
        "isAvailable": true
    },
    {
        "productId": "nokia",
        "productParams": "",
        "isAvailable": true
    },

    {
        "productId": "Lg",
        "productParams": "",
        "isAvailable": false
    }];

let isAvailable = (brand, collections) => collections.some((x) => x.productId === brand && x.isAvailable) 

let x = {
    showButtonSamsung: isAvailable('samsung', collections),
    showButtonNokia: isAvailable('nokia', collections),
    showButtonLg: isAvailable('Lg', collections),
}
console.log(x);
```

Another option :

```
let x = {
    showButtonSamsung: 'samsung',
    showButtonNokia: 'nokia',
    showButtonLg: 'Lg',
}


let isAvailable = (brand, collections) => collections.some((x) => x.productId === brand && x.isAvailable)
x = Object.entries(x).map(([key, value]) => ([key, isAvailable(value, collections)]))
    .reduce((obj, arr) => ({
        ...obj, [arr[0]]: arr[1]
    }), {})

console.log(x);
```

Comment: `array.some(...)` would be better than `array.find(...) !== undefined`